# How to add overlays to layer control dynamically : leaflet

Tags: angular, leaflet

The goal is to add overlays dynamically to the LayerControl.

- Win10
- Angular 7 (CLI) Demo project
  ** https://asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/

The example works, but now I try to add/set the layers and overlays dynamically.
Instead of using the predefined "layersControl" and reference this control in the html I want to create a LayerControl object `this.devLayersControl = new L.Control.Layers();` If I update the html binding to "devLayersControl" the control icon is visible but not useable it is flickering.
Could somebody please give me a snippet how....

```html
<div class="map" 
    leaflet 
    (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
    [leafletOptions]="options" 
    [leafletLayersControl]="devLayersControl">
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { tileLayer, latLng, marker, icon, polyline, point, Map } from 'leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
    selector: 'thevoid-leaflet-map',
    templateUrl: './map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    // Define our base layers so we can reference them multiple times
    openstreetMap = tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        detectRetina: true,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    wikimediaMap = tileLayer('http://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        detectRetina: true,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    // Marker for the top of Mt. Ranier
    summit = marker([46.8523, -121.7603], {
        icon: icon({
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [13, 41],
            iconUrl: 'leaflet/marker-icon.png',
            shadowUrl: 'leaflet/marker-shadow.png'
        })
    });

    // Marker for the parking lot at the base of Mt. Ranier trails
    paradise = marker([46.78465227596462, -121.74141269177198], {
        icon: icon({
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [13, 41],
            iconUrl: 'leaflet/marker-icon.png',
            shadowUrl: 'leaflet/marker-shadow.png'
        })
    });

    // Path from paradise to summit - most points omitted from this example for brevity
    route = polyline([[46.78465227596462, -121.74141269177198],
    [46.80047278292477, -121.73470708541572],
    [46.815471360459924, -121.72521826811135],
    [46.8360239546746, -121.7323131300509],
    [46.844306448474526, -121.73327445052564],
    [46.84979408048093, -121.74325201660395],
    [46.853193528950214, -121.74823296256363],
    [46.85322881676257, -121.74843915738165],
    [46.85119913890958, -121.7519719619304],
    [46.85103829018772, -121.7542376741767],
    [46.85101557523012, -121.75431755371392],
    [46.85140013694763, -121.75727385096252],
    [46.8525277543813, -121.75995212048292],
    [46.85290292836726, -121.76049157977104],
    [46.8528160918504, -121.76042997278273]]);

    // Layers control object with our two base layers and the three overlay layers
    layersControl = {
        baseLayers: {
            'Street Maps': this.openstreetMap,
            'Wikimedia Maps': this.wikimediaMap
        },
        overlays: {
            'Mt. Rainier Summit': this.summit,
            'Mt. Rainier Paradise Start': this.paradise,
            'Mt. Rainier Climb Route': this.route
        }
    };

    // Set the initial set of displayed layers (we could also use the leafletLayers input binding for this)
    options = {
        layers: [this.openstreetMap, this.route, this.summit, this.paradise],
        zoom: 7,
        center: latLng([46.879966, -121.726909])
    };

    /**
     * JSt: tests
     */
    devLayersControl: any;

    googleMap = tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
        detectRetina: true
    });
    googleHybridMap = tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
        detectRetina: true
    });

    constructor() {

        console.log(`MapComponent.constructor(..) called`);
        this.devLayersControl = new L.Control.Layers();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.devLayersControl.addBaseLayer(this.googleHybridMap, "GoogleHybrid");
        this.devLayersControl.addBaseLayer(this.openstreetMap, "Street Maps");
        this.devLayersControl.addBaseLayer(this.wikimediaMap, "Wikimedia Maps");

        this.devLayersControl.addOverlay(this.summit, 'Mt. Rainier Summit');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    }

    onMapReady(map: Map) {

        map.fitBounds(this.route.getBounds(), {
            padding: point(24, 24),
            maxZoom: 12,
            animate: true
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you have any solution ? I want to do the same